# Excel - runtime error 13: Type mismatch?

Tags: excel, types, mismatch

I have this problem with an Excel Form and I don't get it. 
The form has 2 date fields Begin and End Date and 1 CHeckbox called Fixed Period.

The goal is when the checkbox is checked that the period is meant to be 1 year, hence 
End date is recalculated with Begindate as Base.
The VBA code below results in error 13 Type Mismatch on the If statement.

I thought Dates should be converted with CDate or is that nog the problem?
Any pointer appreciated

```
Private Sub BeginDatum_Change()
Static OldValue As String

With Me.BeginDatum
    Debug.Print "Value: "; .Value; " Old Value: "; OldValue
    If CDate(.Value) > CDate(EindDatum.Value) Or CDate(.Value) > Date Then
        Debug.Print "EindDatum " & EindDatum.Value & " is NOT Good"
            .Value = OldValue
    Else
        Sheets("Traject").Range("Begin") = .Value
        OldValue = .Value
        If (FixedPeriod) Then
           EindDatum.Value = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Me.BeginDatum.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what is BeginDatum? since your sub is `BeginDatum_Change' and later you try to get 'BeginDatum.Value`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `CDate`. I think you should have at least tried that? But my guess would be, instead of using *Change* event, try *AfterUpdate*?

Comment: Sorry ... BeginDatum and EindDatum are form fields ... and BeginDatum_Change is the procedure that fires when a change occurs. ALready tried without CDate.  I don't see an AfterUpdate event???

Answer (score 0):

One of these ends up not being a date or is impossible to convert to date.

1. CDate(.Value)
2. CDate(EindDatum.Value)
3. CDate(.Value)

You need to determine whether the inputs represent a valid date before trying to convert.

```
If IsDate(.Value) then
   'use the input
End if
```

Etc...

[IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx)